# Full access from Form2 to Form1

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, forms

**How to create a full access from:   Form 2  to Form1**
So i can use all Textboxes, Datagridviews and the given information from my From1 in my second  Form2

My Plan : User choose a Item in my DataGridView and then automatically my Second Form open, where all informations are given in Textboxes and so on... the user can modify them and save them into my SQL Database, Form2 closed and Form1 opens again

I look at Stackoverflow and google but i dont find a soulution, working for me ...

Comment: Can't you just make all the members of Form1 (controls, properties, etc.) public?

Comment: You can't find solution, because what you are trying to do is not good idea. Pass *data* between forms instead of making their internals visible

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy And how can i Pass Data between my Forms and why its not a good idea? :/

Comment: Basically, there's a lot more stuff in the form than what the other function needs. If someone asks you for your license and registration, do you hand them the contents of your pockets or just the items that they need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And list of persons bound to grid

```
List<Person> people = GetPeople();
peopleGridView.DataSource = people;
```

When you double-click on some row, get data bound person and pass it to second form:

```
private void peopleGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (peopleGridView.CurrentRow == null)
        return;

    Person person = (Person)peopleGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
    using (var editForm = new PersonDetailsForm(person))
    {
        if (editForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        // get updated person data and save them to database
        UpdatePerson(editForm.Person);
    }
}
```

In edit form display person data in controls (you can use data-binding also):

```
public partial class PersonDetailsForm : Form
{
    public PersonEditForm(Person person)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        idLabel.Text = person.Id.ToString();
        nameTextBox.Text = person.Name;
        // etc
    }

    public Person Person
    {
        return new Person {
            Id = Int32.Parse(idLabel.Text),
            Name = nameTextBox.Text
        };
    }     
}
```

Benefits - you can change `PersonEditForm` independently - add/remove controls, change their types, adding data binding etc without changing your main form.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a constructor in your Form2 that takes the parameters that will fill your controls for example:

```
public Form2(string property1, List<object1> objects)
{
    textbox1.text = property1;
    gridview1.DataSource = objects;
    //and so on
}
```

and then call them from form1

```
Form2 form = new Form2(string1,list1);
form.Open();
```

or you can pass a single object to the constuctor and extend its properties in Form2

Answer (score -2):

Transfer all necessary data to a third class and pass the instance as a parameter to form2.